# Knitting, crocheting, and macrame site?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there an SE site that caters to those interested in knitting, crocheting, macrame, and other forms of tailoring?

Comment: Please do come, and be welcome! We have several users who are avid fibrecrafters. :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try [Arts & Crafts Stack Exchange](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/tour)

- [knitting](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knitting)
- [crocheting](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crocheting)
- [macrame](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macrame)